# WebRTC data channel message limit

Tags: python, webrtc, aiortc

I have peers connected through WebRTC, and I'm sending messages through the data channel.

I've read that there are some limits to the data channel of about 16kbs. However, this always was in the context of web browsers.

WebRTC can now be natively used "server-side". I am using the aiortc Python library and I've observed that once I try sending messages of around 100mbs, the operation fails.

Is there a limit on the server side of WebRTC? Is there a way to send large message (gbs)?

Comment: aren't you already pointing out the answer yourself: it seems to be implementation specific. Personally I've had to solve this problem, too, and ended up writing my own "piece meal" class that sends large buffers in small pieces.

Comment: I'm not necessarily hard-commited to the library and I could change that. I'm more interested if there is a difference between WebRTC w/ and w\ browsers.